# How to use conditional parentheses in Positive lookbehind?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, sorting, search

I do have a serie of vim function names that I want to sort using python regex.

```
names = [' function! s:Test2()',  '  function! Test()', ' function! s:WhateverName()', '   function! Test3()']
```

I only want to match the name of the function without `:s`

Why doesn't this regex work?

```
import regex
sorted(names, key=lambda x: regex.findall("(?<=\s*function!\s*(s:)?).*(?=\()", x, regex.IGNORECASE))
```

output:

```
[' function! s:WhateverName()', ' function! s:Test2()', '  function! Test()', '   function! Test3()']
```

Expected output:

```
['  function! Test()', ' function! s:Test2()', '   function! Test3()', ' function! s:WhateverName()']
```

Comment: I don't see any difference between your input and expected output.

Comment: @austin sorry, I copied the output as input. Changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can sort this list by simplifying your regex with capturing word chars that come before the parentheses `(\w+)\(\)`

```py
names = ['  function! Test()', ' function! s:Test2()', '   function! Test3()', ' function! s:WhateverName()']
import re as regex
names = sorted(names, key=lambda x: regex.findall("(\w+)\(\)", x, regex.IGNORECASE))
print(names)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
['  function! Test()', ' function! s:Test2()', '   function! Test3()', ' function! s:WhateverName()']
```

Comment: you could be more specific in your regex and just use `function!\s(?:s:)?(.*)\(\)`

Comment: a look ahead or look behind has to be fixed width. you cant use things like + or * as these mean variable length.

Comment: Chris, can you please explain a bit more about your regex `function!\s(?:s:)?(.*)\(\)`  ?  Why did you put parentheses around `.*` an what does `\(\)` do?

Comment: So the regex says look for the string `function!` followed by a space. Then in a non capturing group look for `s:` 0 or 1 time. Then in a capturing group, capture any chars until you see an open and close bracket. Brackets in regex have special meaning. So  to match a litteral bracket we have to use a backslash to escape the special meaning.

Comment: Chris, I understand it but what's still not clear "capture any chars until you see an open and close bracket". Why a close bracket? Only an open bracket, isn't it? `function! functionname(`

Comment: well you could look just for the open bracket that will work too. I just prefer my regex to be clean and clear so anyone else can understand what its doing. So i personally feel its cleaner to show we are looking for function optionally with s: then the name followed by an open and closed bracket. Of course this only holds  true if all your functions have empty brackets.

Answer (score 1):

The output and input are the same, just ordered differently.

You could order it using regex:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r"(\w+)\(\)") 

names = ['  function! Test()', ' function! s:Test2()', '   function! Test3()', ' function! s:WhateverName()']
names = sorted(names, key=lambda k: pattern.findall(k, flags=re.IGNORECASE))
print(names)
```

Comment: yes thats the issue the user has, he is trying to sort by just the function name regardless of if its prefixed with `s:` or not

Comment: sorry, I copied the output as input. Changed it.

Comment: Updated my answer, didn't see that.

Comment: @alexisdevarennes I would like to know why my regex doesn't work and how to use parentheses within a positive lookbehind.